# Generate unique variables and reuse them

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

There are questions regarding generating unique variables with the C preprocessor, and I know how to do this. I'd like the next step: **reusing the names later**.

I'd like to have, for instance, two `define` names, `STARTT` and `STOPT` that practically start a timer and stop it, so that I may use the very same names throughout the project simply as

```
// Get the cool STARTT/STOPT macros
#include "coolmacros"

myclass::myclass()
{
    STARTT
    // Do something
    STOPT
}

void myclass::compute(double f, std::vector<double> &v)
{
    STARTT
    // Do something
    STOPT
}
```

Right now I just print what is happening as follows

```
#define STARTT info(">>> START %s::%s", demangle(typeid(*this).name()).c_str(), __FUNCTION__);
#define STOPT  info(">>> STOP  %s::%s", demangle(typeid(*this).name()).c_str(), __FUNCTION__);
```

Is it possible to add a timer to the macros, so that `STOPT` knows what symbol `STARTT` generated, and I can add something like the following?

```
#define STOPT  info(">>> STOP  %s::%s %d", demangle(typeid(*this).name()).c_str(), __FUNCTION__, GET_STARTT_TIMER().elapsed());
```

Thanks!

Comment: C++  has other solution than C. Choose your language.

Comment: I feel the need to elaborate upon the comment written by @Jarod42: "C++ has other solution than C. Choose your language." If you view my profile, you'll notice that I'm quite familiar with C, and I'm fairly sure that **it's impossible to generate unique identifiers in standard-compliant C using the preprocessor**, at least if you plan on using macros with the signatures defined above. I think you'd need to introduce an argument (see [molbdrillo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35769686/1989425) for an example of this)...

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, you're right. However the question asks about variables, and this is valid in C and C++. The timer will be language dependent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, you can use an object and rely on the destructor:

```
class TimerThing
{
public:
    TimerThing(const char* name, const char* what, const char* where) 
        : start_time(something()), 
          m_name(name), 
          m_what(what), 
          m_where(where) 
    {
         info(">>> START %s %s::%s", m_name, m_what, m_where);
    }
    ~TimerThing()
    {
        info(">>> STOP %s %s::%s %d", m_name, m_what, m_where, elapsed());
    }
private:
    int elapsed() { /* whatever */ }
    something start_time;
    const char* name;
    const char* m_what;
    const char* m_where;
};

#define SCOPE_TIMER(x) TimerThing x(#x, demangle(typeid(*this).name()).c_str(), __FUNCTION__)

class Foo
{
    public:
    void f()
    {   
        SCOPE_TIMER(f_timer);
        {
            SCOPE_TIMER(f_subtimer);
        }       
    }
};
```

Possible output:

```
>>> START f_timer Foo Foo::f
>>> START f_subtimer Foo Foo::f
>>> STOP f_subtimer Foo Foo::f 10
>>> STOP f_timer Foo Foo::f 12
```

(Warning: untested code with completely imaginary timing functions.)

Comment: In the interest of maintainability, it seems to make sense to remove the declaration from `STARTT` so those maintaining the code later can clearly see that it's a declaration without backtracking. For example, rather than writing `STARTT(f_timer);` I would write `TimerThing timer_identity(f_timer);` and `#define timer_identity(x) x(#x, demangle(typeid(*this).name()).c_str(), __FUNCTION__)`

Comment: I'd just like to clarify that this is only a *minor stylistic* criticism, and even despite any potential disagreements you already got my +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's not very flexible approach. What if you'll later need to measure inner scope in the same function?

You could have something like this:

```
STARTT(id1);
{    
...
    STARTT(id2);
    ...
    STOPT(id2);
    ...
}
STOPT(id1);
```

This uses user-provided name. Still it can be done better:

```
{ TIMEIT;
    ...
    { TIMEIT;
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here you don't need 2 macros, just one is sufficient if combined with C++ scope. It would define a local var of your custom type that in constructor gets current time and in destructor measures time passed and does something with it, like printing.

And strictly speaking you don't need a macro at all:

```
{ TimeIt ti;
    ...
}
```